# Error at new SubprocessError in ionic cordova build ios

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, xcode8, ionic4

I'm going to build ios platform on Mac and I have this problem.

I use macOS 10.12, Xcode 8 and Ionic 4. I've tried `"ionic cordova platform rm ios"` and `"ionic cordova platform add ios"` and build but it's still not working.

> Daos-Mac:Ionic_UI_V1 daovu$ ionic cordova build ios

```
ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=ios
```

> Error at new SubprocessError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:40:23) ...

Comment: can you add screenshot of ionic info

Comment: Oh It's my fault, my node-module folder is error, I have overwrite it by a node-module of new project. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @VũMinh you are correct overwriting worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and then run `npm install`

Problem will be solved

Answer (score 1):

try to delete "node_modules" folder and run `npm install`

Comment: could you elaborate the post. This does not cover a hint about global and local modules and where to look for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try :--

1) Remove ios platform :

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
```

2) Add ios platform :

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

3) Prepare ios platform (send source code to ios platform)

```
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

4) Run build and install :

```
Open xcode - select profile - run application
```

Comment: I have follow your direction and I have a same problem at step 3: "ionic cordova prepare ios".

Comment: MacOS 10.12 does not support Xcode 10. However, I have fix that problem and thanks you very much. Now, I'm stuck at step 4, the Terminal say that 
"The files /Users/daovu/Downloads/Ionic_UI_V2/xcode ... /Users/daovu/Downloads/Ionic_UI_V2/application do not exist."

Comment: I am getting same issue at step 4.                                                                              getting this error Error

    at new SubprocessError 
(/Users/admin/Desktop/SanctionRulesAppSVN/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:40:23)
    at ChildProcess.p.on 
(/Users/admin/Desktop/SanctionRulesAppSVN/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:128:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1001:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)

Comment: I just create new project in ionic 4  and run in ios. it is working fine.

Comment: but i am using everything updated version like xcode 10

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when installing the [Calendar Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/calendar/) on a Mac 10.14.5 with Ionic v4/XCode 10.2.1.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-calendar
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-calendar
Error

at new SubprocessError
(/Users/brippe/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:40:23)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
(/Users/brippe/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:113:27)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
```

I solved it by running:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
```

then reinstalling cordova again

```
npm install -g cordova
```

finally successfully installing the calendar plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-calendar
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-calendar

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Adding cordova-plugin-calendar to package.json
```

I'm using [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/ios/), so my build process was still functioning once I synced.

```
npx cap sync
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, executing the `npm audit fix` command solved the problem.
It might be a simple dependency failure

Comment: in my case, this cause the problem, after audit project stop...

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 11.4, Ionic 6.7.0**

In my case the error was I had a folder named "iOS" on root level thats why, cordova was confused between iOS Projects. Renaming It or deleting it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it happen because you **did not installed** cordova globally. to install **cordova** run the below command::

```
npm install -g cordova
```

run this command on terminal to install it...